# What does ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore in Newtonsoft.json exactly do?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Can anyone present me a scenario where it can be used.
What I understand by **ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore** is if you have an object A which references object B and B references C and C again references A (A->B->C->A), then when serializing, it will end up in endless loop between C and A, which can be avoided using below. Am I right?

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, 
     Formatting.Indented, 
     new JsonSerializerSetting()
         {
             ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
         } 
 ));
```

I am having self referencing loop issue which gets solved by using the above, but I want to understand exactly what it is doing as the above line is the meat of the application (critical meat)

Comment: JsonSerializerSettings()

Answer (score 47):

The documentation on this is available here: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm

As of this writing, the behavior is described there as follows (with emphasis mine):

> `ReferenceLoopHandling.Error`: By default Json.NET will error if a
>   reference loop is encountered (otherwise the serializer will get into
>   an infinite loop).
>
> **`ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`**: Json.NET will ignore objects in
>   reference loops and not serialize them. **The first time an object is
>   encountered it will be serialized as usual but if the object is
>   encountered as a child object of itself the serializer will skip
>   serializing it.**
>
> `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize`: This option forces Json.NET to
>   serialize objects in reference loops. This is useful if objects are
>   nested but not indefinitely.

Comment: what will happen in case of  PreserveReferencesHandling ?