# JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. With ASP.NET Core MVC And Blazor Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I added Blazor components in my ASP.NET Core MVC application, when I am passing a model to the component, I got this error:

> JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

So, I tried add all these options in my `startup.cs`:

```cs
services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options => {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 256;
            });
```

```
services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                opt.SerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 256;
            });
```

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
            });
```

```
services.AddMvc(opt => { ... })
        .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                {
                    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                });
```

But none of them work, nothing happens, and I always get the same error.

I use the component like this:

```cs
<component type="typeof(CompBlazor)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-Client="Model"/>
```

This is the code in my Blazor component:

```cs
@code {
     [Parameter]
     public Client cli {get;set;}
}
```

No matter what I do, I always get that same error.

Comment: Your question shows an object called `Client`.  What is it, because it is almost certainly the cause of your problem?  Probably a circular reference as @Chen suggests in his answer.  However, without more information, we're all guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use nested models and end up with an infinite loop, like this:

Model:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Reservation> Reservation { get; set; } = new List<Reservation>();
}

public class Reservation
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{            
    var client = new Client() { Name="test"};
    client.Reservation.Add(new Reservation { Client = client });
    client.Reservation.Add(new Reservation { Client = client });
    return View(client);
}
```

Doing so will make the final result an infinite loop causing this error to occur.

I tested a solution to this problem, using `Newtonsoft.Json`'s `JsonConvert` for serialization and deserialization. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works. you can refer to my test code below:

Insatll [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.3-beta1) NuGet Package.

And then in Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{         
    var client = new Client() { Name="test"};
    client.Reservation.Add(new Reservation { Client = client });
    client.Reservation.Add(new Reservation { Client = client });

    var ClientSerialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client,
         Formatting.Indented,
         new JsonSerializerSettings()
         {
             ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
         }
    );
    Client ClientDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Client>(ClientSerialize);

    return View(ClientDeserialize);
}
```

View:

```
<component type="typeof(CompBlazor)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-cli="Model" />
```

Blazor component:

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Client cli { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more details about `ReferenceLoopHandling`, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205542/18789859).

Also, you can try to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210264/18789859). I tested it but it didn't work for me, not sure if it will work for your code.

Comment: this worked, thanks! but i don't understand why they denied my question